# Unity3D Android Spotify Plugin causes signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, libspotify

I have written a Unity3D plugin to connect my application with Spotify through libspotify.
Windows version works fine, but android version crash about 5 seconds after log in Spotify.

Here is the adt logcat

```
 Build fingerprint: 'rk31sdk/rk31sdk/rk31sdk:4.2.2/JDQ39/eng.hotack.20130619.182852:eng/test-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 pid: 9984, tid: 10003, name: UnityMain  >>> com.unity3d.player 

 stack:
          6a818d38  00000000
          6a818d3c  00000000
          6a818d40  00000000
          6a818d44  00000000
          6a818d48  00000000
          6a818d4c  00000000
          6a818d50  00000000
          6a818d54  00000000
          6a818d58  00000000
          6a818d5c  00000000
          6a818d60  6a818d94
          6a818d64  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818d68  00000003
          6a818d6c  67392180
          6a818d70  e3a070ad
          6a818d74  ef9000ad
     #00  6a818d78  00000000
          6a818d7c  6446d000
          6a818d80  64465000
          6a818d84  644650e0
          6a818d88  64456010
          6a818d8c  64456010
          6a818d90  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818d94  00000000
          6a818d98  00000000
          6a818d9c  00000000
          6a818da0  00000000
          6a818da4  00000000
          6a818da8  00000000
          6a818dac  0006447b
          6a818db0  64471ba8
          6a818db4  00000000
          ........  ........
     #01  6a818e60  00000000
          6a818e64  00000000
          6a818e68  00000000
          6a818e6c  00000000
          6a818e70  00000000
          6a818e74  6a818ea4
          6a818e78  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818e7c  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818e80  6a818ebc
          6a818e84  695bf808  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so (GC_stopped_mark+536)
     #02  6a818e88  00000000
          6a818e8c  00000000
          6a818e90  00000000
          6a818e94  695c963c  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so (clear_marks_for_block)
          6a818e98  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818e9c  695be8a8  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so (GC_never_stop_func)
          6a818ea0  00002010
          6a818ea4  00000000
          6a818ea8  6a818ebc
          6a818eac  695c98dc  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so (GC_clear_marks+36)
          6a818eb0  696af604  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so
          6a818eb4  00002010
          6a818eb8  6a818eec
          6a818ebc  695bf238  /mnt/asec/com.unity3d.player-2/lib/libmono.so (GC_try_to_collect_inner+528)

 memory near r1:
     20041fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20041ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     20042090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     200420a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     200420b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     200420c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     200420d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff

 memory near r4:
     696af5e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     696af5f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     696af604 003b84fc 00000000 00000000 40132c09
     696af614 40133d61 4012f678 40142a5b 40124d50
     696af624 4013b8f9 4012f158 40125d75 4012e608
     696af634 40145e95 401da3f8 4013fb71 40123f1d
     696af644 4013c207 4012eecc 40132d43 40138b95
     696af654 4013c075 401350a1 40133c11 401de030
     696af664 4012f600 40133dd1 4012db41 4012f178
     696af674 4012f484 40138ad3 4013371d 40123f31
     696af684 4012fba0 401335ad 40124524 40137911
     696af694 40124470 4013561d 4012ec10 401d3e10
     696af6a4 40124114 4012f1d4 4012ee5c 4013bfd1
     696af6b4 4012e400 401e0f28 401255fc 4012e094
     696af6c4 4012ec2c 4012fbd1 40139015 4013bf21
     696af6d4 40138711 4014bb81 4013b5d9 4012ebf4

 memory near r6:
     67f4b988 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b998 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4b9f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba08 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba18 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba28 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba38 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba48 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba58 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba68 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4ba78 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff

 memory near r7:
     67f4bb80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bb90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bba0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bbb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bbc0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bbd0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bbe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bbf0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
     67f4bc70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff

 memory near r9:
     69be7f60 e1a00004 e08f2002 e58dc008 e3a0c001
     69be7f70 e58dc000 ebfc4dd4 e1a00004 ebf9d120
     69be7f80 005f1be0 004ea1ac 004e41a4 e59f30a4
     69be7f90 e92d4030 e79f3003 e24dd024 e58d0014
     69be7fa0 e5930000 ebfc41be e250c000 0a000013
     69be7fb0 e59f3084 e79f3003 e5934000 e5d43001
     69be7fc0 e3530000 0a00000b e28d5018 e28d1014
     69be7fd0 e1a00005 ebfa2283 e1a00004 e1a01005
     69be7fe0 e3a02000 ebfab6e2 e59d0018 e28d101c
     69be7ff0 e240000c eb119433 e28dd024 e8bd8030
     69be8000 e59f4038 e1a0100c e59f2034 e300387d
     69be8010 e08f4004 e58dc004 e1a00004 e08f2002
     69be8020 e58dc008 e3a0c001 e58dc000 ebfc4da6
     69be8030 e1a00004 ebf9d0f2 005f1b18 005f16e4
     69be8040 004ea21c 004e40ec e59f3100 e92d4070
     69be8050 e79f3003 e24dd018 e1a05000 e5930000

 memory near sl:
     64474fdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     64474fec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     64474ffc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6447500c 00000000 67777780 00000000 67781408
     6447501c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6447502c 00000000 64610db0 00000000 00000000
     6447503c 00000000 6777b780 00000000 00000000
     6447504c 00000000 64482c80 00000000 00000000
     6447505c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6447506c 00000000 6777acb0 00000000 00000000
     6447507c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6447508c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6447509c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     644750ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     644750bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     644750cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

 memory near fp:
     6a818e3c 696af604 00000003 00000000 67568c50
     6a818e4c 64613e38 6a819778 6a81975c 6a818e84
     6a818e5c 695c9d10 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6a818e6c 00000000 00000000 6a818ea4 696af604
     6a818e7c 696af604 6a818ebc 695bf808 00000000
     6a818e8c 00000000 00000000 695c963c 696af604
     6a818e9c 695be8a8 00002010 00000000 6a818ebc
     6a818eac 695c98dc 696af604 00002010 6a818eec
     6a818ebc 695bf238 00000000 67568c50 00004e93
     6a818ecc 000296a4 00002010 695be8a8 6a818eec
     6a818edc 695bed28 696af604 696af604 6a818f1c
     6a818eec 695c0a90 6a818f1c 695bde00 67abb000
     6a818efc 00000000 00000000 00000003 00000003
     6a818f0c 00000003 0000003d 696af604 6a818f4c
     6a818f1c 695c7510 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6a818f2c 00000804 00000000 00000003 00000001

 memory near ip:
     696af5e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     696af5f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     696af604 003b84fc 00000000 00000000 40132c09
     696af614 40133d61 4012f678 40142a5b 40124d50
     696af624 4013b8f9 4012f158 40125d75 4012e608
     696af634 40145e95 401da3f8 4013fb71 40123f1d
     696af644 4013c207 4012eecc 40132d43 40138b95
     696af654 4013c075 401350a1 40133c11 401de030
     696af664 4012f600 40133dd1 4012db41 4012f178
     696af674 4012f484 40138ad3 4013371d 40123f31
     696af684 4012fba0 401335ad 40124524 40137911
     696af694 40124470 4013561d 4012ec10 401d3e10
     696af6a4 40124114 4012f1d4 4012ee5c 4013bfd1
     696af6b4 4012e400 401e0f28 401255fc 4012e094
     696af6c4 4012ec2c 4012fbd1 40139015 4013bf21
     696af6d4 40138711 4014bb81 4013b5d9 4012ebf4

 memory near sp:
     6a818d58 00000000 00000000 6a818d94 696af604
     6a818d68 00000003 67392180 e3a070ad ef9000ad
     6a818d78 00000000 6446d000 64465000 644650e0
     6a818d88 64456010 64456010 696af604 00000000
     6a818d98 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6a818da8 00000000 0006447b 64471ba8 00000000
     6a818db8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     6a818dc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000a64
     6a818dd8 00000000 64606df8 64612fc8 6a818da4
     6a818de8 000003f2 00000000 00000000 00040000
     6a818df8 644270b0 6447bee0 64456010 67392180
     6a818e08 6a818da4 00000060 000000ff 00004000
     6a818e18 00004000 64471ba8 6447bee0 6a818dac
     6a818e28 000003b8 00000000 01000000 01000000
     6a818e38 6a818ea4 696af604 00000003 00000000
     6a818e48 67568c50 64613e38 6a819778 6a81975c

 code around pc:
     695ca6c4 e1a03007 e0633002 e51b2088 e0823003
     695ca6d4 e50b3088 e2477004 ea000000 e1a00000
     695ca6e4 e5973000 e50b3060 e2477004 e51b3060
     695ca6f4 e153000a 3a000003 e51b3060 e1530009
     695ca704 2a000000 ea00000e e1560007 8a000173
     695ca714 e5973000 e50b3060 e2477004 e51b3060
     695ca724 e153000a 3a000003 e51b3060 e1530009
     695ca734 2a000000 ea000002 e1560007 9affffe6
     695ca744 ea000167 ea0000b4 e5968000 e1a03008
     695ca754 e153000a 3a0000af e1a03008 e1530009
     695ca764 2a0000ac e50b8058 e51b3058 e1a03623
     695ca774 e2033007 e1a03183 e24b20c8 e0823003
     695ca784 e50b3054 e51b3054 e5932000 e51b3058
     695ca794 e1a03623 e1520003 1a000003 e51b3054
     695ca7a4 e5933004 e50b305c ea000025 e51b3058
     695ca7b4 e1a03b23 e59f2564 e7942002 e2833daa

 code around lr:
     695ca920 0a000003 e51b3058 e1a00003 ebffdaf9
     695ca930 ea000039 e51b3058 e1a00003 ebffdaab
     695ca940 ea000035 e51b2050 e51b304c e0633002
     695ca950 e50b3050 ea000000 e1a00000 e51b305c
     695ca960 e2832018 e51b3050 e1a032c3 e1a03103
     695ca970 e0825003 e5953000 e50b3048 e51b3050
     695ca980 e203301f e3a02001 e1a03312 e50b3044
     695ca990 e51b2048 e51b3044 e0023003 e3530000
     695ca9a0 1a00001d e51b2048 e51b3044 e1823003
     695ca9b0 e5853000 e51b305c e593500c e3550000
     695ca9c0 0a000015 e51b30d8 e2833008 e50b30d8
     695ca9d0 e51b20d8 e51b30e0 e1520003 3a000003
     695ca9e0 e51b00d8 ebfffdd0 e1a03000 e50b30d8
     695ca9f0 e51b3050 e1a02103 e51b3058 e3c33eff
     695caa00 e3c3300f e0823003 e1a02003 e51b30d8
     695caa10 e5832000 e51b30d8 e5835004 e2866004

 memory map around fault addr 67f4bba0:
     67ecb000-67ecc000
     (no map for address)
     67f4c000-67f76000
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

libspotify on Android has always been very unreliable and problematic. Spotify has just released a [new Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/), you should migrate your project to that, as libspotify is now considered deprecated for that platform.